# Update wpa_supplicant.conf raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I had a set a network connection with my home router from my raspberry pi using the wpa_supplicant.conf in the boot partition of the sd card, but I changed it and now it doesn't connect to the new router, what did I do wrong?

the code looks like this

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="WIFI_SSID"
scan_ssid=1
psk="WIFI_PASSWORD"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try indenting the lines within the braces - using 1 tab, so that the contents are;-

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="WIFI_SSID"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="WIFI_PASSWORD"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```